# Generate Parity-check matrix from Generator matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a function in (**numpy**) or well-tested function to calculate Parity-check matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity-check_matrix)

from Generator matrix?

P.S.

I did not find solution on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct parity-check matrix is nullspace of generator
matrix in modulo 2. There is solution for this in `scipy` but this function
give non integer nullspace. You can use `sympy` but it can be slow for big
matrices.

```
"""
>>> np.set_string_function(str)
>>> h
[[0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [1 0 1 1 0 1 0]
 [1 1 0 1 0 0 1]]
>>> (g @ h.T) % 2
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]
"""
import sympy
import numpy as np

g = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]])
h = np.array(sympy.Matrix(g).nullspace()) % 2
```

where `h` is parity-check matrix.